# Error trying to confirm an email using Identity.UserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, .net-5, asp.net5

I'm using SendGrid API to send validation email. It was working fine on SendGrid and Azure, where my application was hosted before. But, after a deploy to IIS Server, on my VPS, I'm getting error when I try to confirm the user email return from SendGrid:

```
var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);
```

From Event Viewer log, the warning is:

```
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager
EventId: 9
SpanId: 3830373dac59b144
TraceId: 2654243922e29b43b4ade992e096d1d3
ParentId: 0000000000000000
RequestId: 800000fd-0001-f300-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /Identity/Account/EmailConfirmation
ActionId: 65237a3f-acf5-4dda-93d6-c37a34f1a351
ActionName: Kepler.MVC.Areas.Identity.Controllers.AccountController.EmailConfirmation (Kepler.MVC)

VerifyUserTokenAsync() failed with purpose: EmailConfirmation for user.
```

Is that error above about token validation? Why is happening?

Besides that, throwing an error exception, the error on Event Viewer log is:

```
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer
EventId: 2
SpanId: 3830373dac59b144
TraceId: 2654243922e29b43b4ade992e096d1d3
ParentId: 0000000000000000
RequestId: 800000fd-0001-f300-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /Identity/Account/EmailConfirmation

Connection ID "17509995357122068732", Request ID "800000fd-0001-f300-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

Exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at AspNetCore.Views_Shared_Error.ExecuteAsync() in C:\Users\gutox\source\repos\Gutobarroso\GooGit\Kepler.MVC\Views\Shared\Error.cshtml:line 9
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
```

I noticed that the path to Error.cshtml is pointing to my localhost C:\Users\gutox\source\repos\Gutobarroso\GooGit\Kepler.MVC\Views\Shared\Error.cshtml:line 9

But I have done the deploy to the IIS Server Hosting. I'am not using localhost anymore. How/Where can I change it?

I will appreciate for some help. I'm using .Net 5, IIS 10.

Answer (score 0):

My fault. I was passing a single quote at the end of my callback url token. So, the tokens were diferents when comparing.